# Interesting IOS 6 user agent

Tags: ios6, user-agent

Could any one of you please tell me what causes the Safari version number and build number to be missing from the user agent string?

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B350
```

In most cases this is what we are seeing -

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25
```

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that when Safari isn't present that the user agent isn't Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok basically if you install the Google Search App and visit a site via the app then the user agent will be `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B350`

Hope this helps someone.